# How to achieve hover state in iPad / iPhone links?

Tags: css, iphone, ipad, ios

I've noticed on a lot of sites recently that the hover state is being achieved on links.

For example there is a bunch of links, you touch one, it turns red, you touch it again and the link works.

I have tried various CSS methods to achieve this but so far no luck.

Can anyone shed any light?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an article that talks about the iOS :hover/[double tap issue](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/07/05/ios-has-a-hover-problem/) .

Answer (score 0):

That's not a hover event, to me it seems more like a click event. You click, the color changes (or better still, it toggles)

Comment: I think it's hover as by going to the same site on a computer, you see the event happening on hover.

Comment: Go to eBay.com/electronics and use the nav menu down the side of the page. On a desktop the drop down menus appear when you hover over them. However on iPad you need to touch the nav to make the drop down menus appear.

Comment: if you set up a hover, when you visit a site with a touch device, you have to click on the item, hence briefly "hovering" it, and it will trigger the hover event.

Comment: I am looking for the "hover" event to stay until it is touched a second time. Check out the eBay example I put above.

Comment: What you mean is, on desktop it's a hover, while on mobile it's a click event?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try these toggle/switch examples: [css toggle](http://ghinda.net/css-toggle-switches/)